# Usage of @Value properties in mockito test cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have a yml file where I am storing my variables. I am accessing these variables in my program by using @Value annotation. The problem comes when I am writing mock test cases for such methods, I get null pointer exception in my test method. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.
I am making use of @TestPropertySource right now. I need the correct way of doing this.

Here is what I have tried so far.
My yml file looks like this, with many properties in it:

```
car:
services:
  clientId: abcde
  authTokenUrl: ....
  .....

public Class CarExecution(){
@Value("${car.services.clientId}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${car.services.authTokenUrl}")
private String authTokenUrl;
public String getAccessToken() {
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
headers.set(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("grant_type=password" + "&client_id=" + clientId ,headers);
ResponseEntity<Access> response = restTemplate.exchange(authTokenUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity,A.class);
return response.getBody().token_type + " " +
    response.getBody().access_token;

}
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
     "car.services.clientId = clientId ","car.services.authTokenUrl = authTokenUrl",
})
public class CarTest {
    @Value("${car.services.clientId}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${car.services.authTokenUrl}")
    private String authTokenUrl;
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.set(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(
            "grant_type=password&client_id=null", headers);
    authTokenUrl = "";
    new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    A access = new A();
    access.access_token = "token";
    access.token_type = "type";
    response = new ResponseEntity<>(access, HttpStatus.OK);
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(authTokenUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, A.class))
            .thenReturn(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with your `Runner` class as `MockitoJUnitRunner` doesn't initialise any beans or `@Value` annotations.

Spring's answer to it is `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` which does these bits for you (documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html)).

Try replacing `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`.